# c# converting letters to numbers for binary search

Tags: c#, algorithm, encoding, character-encoding

Learning search algorithms. I'm interested in where this question can lead, and what you could recommend me looking into to add into the idea.  Do you know of any quick methods, references, etc... ? Any depth you can add would be cool.

Im  coding the alphabet for a binary search, relying on a string as something like

(pseudocode)

```
        "indent = 0, A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4"
```

so a string "bab dab" would return 2120412.

Then the numbers go into some method contain an algorithm similar to this:

(pseudo example)

```
        int min = 0;
        int N =  total.Length;
        int max = N - 1;
        do
        {
            int mid = (min + max) / 2;
            if (searchKey > total[mid])
                min = mid + 1;
            else
                max = mid - 1;
            if (total[mid] == searchInp)
                return mid;

        } while (min <= max);
        return -1;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Do you need help with something? Please be more specific. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it's just a broad question in which i'm try to see which paths it can lead being as there are many answers to this issue, i'm curious to see what people would say by simply asking a question that isn't exactly about a specific problem, rather the methodology

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can cast a `char` to an `int`, which'll give you the [ASCII value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) of the character. For example, A = 65, a = 97, etc. Here's a code sample to illustrate this (you can tweak this to suit your own purposes):

```
private static int[] StringToIntArray(string str)
    {
        List<int> ints = new List<int>();

        foreach (char chr in str)
        {
            // Technically you don't have to be explicit about the cast but I include it here for clarity
            int chrAsInt = (int)chr;

            // Do the following if you don't care about capital vs. lowercase
            // Otherwise, tweak the numbering system a little
            if (chrAsInt >= 97)
            {
                ints.Add(chrAsInt - 96);
            }
            else
            {
                ints.Add(chrAsInt - 64);
            }
        }

        return ints.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: *magic number* `97` looks ugly, why not `if (chr >= 'a') ints.Add(chr - `a` + 1)...` etc.